# Jar produced by "Package required libraries into JAR" doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar, executable-jar

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302894/what-is-the-difference-between-runnable-jar-library-handling-options).

I've done a mvc TicTacToe with Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: 2021-12 M3 (4.22.0 M3). It's a java project (not maven) and it's using JavaSE-17 libs as JRE System Library (installed latest jdk).
I'm using swing libs, action listeners, action events ecc ecc. Standard libs you find in your java installation.

Right click on project folder --> Export... --> Runnable jar file --> **Extract required libraries into generated JAR**

and my program works as expected, like when I run the main class inside Eclipse.

Right click on project folder --> Export... --> Runnable jar file --> **Package required libraries into JAR**

and my program starts but doesn't work as expected: looks like my AI part doesn't work, some of my little animations don't work too ([animations of this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320447/jlabel-text-not-being-displayed-correctly-after-some-quickly-repeated-action-eve), this one is working tho) and my new game button has a strange behaviour (it keeps looking pressed until I move the mouse cursor away from its button area).

Now: I've looked inside both jars and the only differences are:

1. the package one contains a "org" folder the working one hasn't: [image]
2. the MANIFEST.MF file inside the META-INF folder is slighty different. In the package one is:

   ```
      Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
      Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
      Rsrc-Main-Class: Main
      Class-Path: .
   ```

in the working one is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: .
```

As far as I'm understading, I'm not using external libs. This is my eclipse project folder:[image]

and this is my build path: [image]

I don't know what I'm missing... I've included both folders (src and pics... the latter is just a folder with images I correctly see in both exports)

My question: why the jar produced by exporting with **Package required libraries into JAR** it's not properly working in my case?

Comment: How is the code loading these resources?

Comment: If you mean the pic folder, by getClass().getResource(Pics.MYPIC) with Pics being a class full of a bunch of static fields like this: public static final String WIN = "/win.png";

Comment: How is `/win.png` used to load the image? BTW - If using `getResource`, the leading `/` implies a path from the root of the Jar, so the correct path might be `/pics/win.png`.

Comment: What you mean by "how `/win.png` used to load the image?" I mean: `/win.png` is just the path of the pic file inside my project folder (see last pic of my post: since I've included the "pics" folder in my build path I should be able to refer to each pic in that folder like this: `/picName.png` ). The assignment is for the most part something like this: `JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Pics.MYPIC)));`
I indeed correctly displays pics in both scenarios... I mean, the problem should not be the way my program loads pics